# Listings adds vertical whitespaces in the rest of the PDF

Tags: listings, vertical-alignment, white-space

I've made the command `codeblock` to show code blocks in a box with:

```
\newtcblisting[auto counter]{codeblock}[2][]{
    sharp corners, 
    fonttitle = \bfseries,
    colframe = gray,
    listing only, 
    listing options = {
        basicstyle = \footnotesize\ttfamily,
        language = java
    }, 
    title = Código \thetcbcounter: #2, #1}

\newcommand\code[1]{
  \tikz[baseline=(s.base)]{
    \node(s)[fill=gray!20,draw=gray]{\texttt{#1}};
  }
}
```

The problem I have is that sometimes in the previous page it generate whitespaces, I guess Latex tries to make the text density vertically equal, see the following image:

[image]

But this doesn't happen with new `chapters` or `sections`:

[image]

I feel that the vertical whitespaces that my `codeblock` produce are ugly, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You have not shown any relevant code so it is hard to debug but presumably you have `\flushbottom` in force which forces latex to stretch the last line to the bottom of the page (because your code listing is unbreakable once you put it in the tikz node)  perhaps you want `\raggedbottom` or put the code listing in a float (floats move exactly to avoid bad page breaks like this)

Comment: You could try loading `tcolorbox` with the option `breakable` and then add the same to the definition of `codeblock`. This should enable these boxes to break over pages, (Not tested because of lack of a MWE.)